# "Use of undeclared identifier 'IntQueue' " even though it is defined

Tags: c++

I am getting an error message saying the use of undeclared identifier 'IntQueue' in vscode and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I have tried renaming the file but still does not work. I created a separate header file that has the class defined and I  included the header file in the main cpp file that has all the constructors defined. But I cannot figure out a way to solve the issue.

```
//This is the IntQueue.h header file
#ifdef _IntQueue_
#define _IntQueue_
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class IntQueue {
    int* numbers;
    int size;
    int front;
    int back;
public:
    IntQueue (unsigned int n);
    IntQueue();
    ~IntQueue();
    int getSize() {return size;}
    int getFront() {return front;}
    int getBack() {return back;}
    void incSize();
    void pop();
    int frontNumber();
    void push(int i);
    void reverse();
};

#endif

//This is the IntQueue.cpp file (incomplete)

#include "IntQueue.h"

IntQueue::IntQueue (unsigned int n) {
    size = n;
    numbers = new int[size];
    front = 0;
    back = 0;
}

IntQueue::IntQueue() {
    size = 100;
    front = 0;
    back = 0
    numbers = new int [size];
}
```

Comment: `#ifdef _IntQueue_` should be ifndef

Comment: I'm not sure about this issue (other than generic "did you check for typos"-style advice), but a couple other tips: 1. You shouldn't use `using namespace std;`, especially in a header file; if you must use `using namespace` somewhere, it should only be in the `.cpp` files to not interfere with anybody else using your header. 2. Look into [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), instead of setting data members in the constructor body. 3. You are not allowed to use names that start with an underscore and then a capital letter.

Comment: Agreeing with 3, those names are reserved for usage in standard library

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
#ifdef _IntQueue_
```

To

```
#ifndef _IntQueue_
```

When your `.cpp` file `#include`'s your `.h` file, `_IntQueue_` has not been declared yet, so the `#ifdef` skips the entire content of the `.h` file, and so the compiler doesn't know anything about your `IntQueue` class.